# Seeking for usage clarity on 3 dataframe options for Redis Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, redis, apache-spark-connector

Can anyone please help me elaborate briefly on below Redis spark data frame options with examples.

1. max.pipeline.size
2. scan.count
3. iterator.grouping.size

I have been through the Redis spark documentation available on github, however the information mentioned there did not helped me understand the concept in detail.

`I tried it using those options, but working of an option is not fully understood`